# Is it always possible to factorize a symmetric matrix $xx^T$ into $Avv^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For a given matrix $xx^T$ and a given positive definite matrix $A$, can we always find a vector $v$ so that $xx^T = Avv^T$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not always possible. Take $x = (1,1)$ and $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Letting $v = (a,b)$, for your equation to be true, we would have to have

$$
xx^T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = Avv^T = \begin{pmatrix} 2a^2 & 2ab \\ ab & b^2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

But we have $2ab = ab = 1$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, $x$ is a column vector.

If $x=0$, surely you can pick $v=0$.

If $x\ne0$, the equation $xx^T=Avv^T$ implies that both $Av$ and $v$ are nonzero vectors parallel to $x$. It follows that $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$. Conversely, if $Ax=\lambda x$, then $xx^T=Avv^T$ when $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}x$.